# Manually bind a row in a repeater, to avoid losing viewstate data

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, repeater, viewstate

I'm working on a page that uses a repeater to display a list of custom controls, each containing two dropdown lists.

On a click on the `Add control` button, the page adds a new row on the repeater, and a click on one of the `Delete control` buttons embedded in each control removes the relevant control from the repeater.

The delete part seems to work, (setting `NamingController.Visible` to `false`), but the add part fails, as once I add the new control, a call to a new `repeater.DataBind()` loses all viewstate data, preventing the dropdownlists from retrieving the values they had before postback.

Is there a way to manually bind the added control to the repeater without calling a full databind ? Or is there any other way to add a control without losing data ?

Here's some code (I only left what seems relevant, please let me know if you think I forgot to specify something) :

**Page.aspx:**

```
<asp:Button ID="addControl" runat="server" Text="Add control" />
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc:CustomControlWithDropDownLists ID="custom" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Page.aspx.cs:**

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    repeater.DataSource = GetDataSource();
    repeater.DataBind();
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addControl.Click += (sndr, args) =>
    {
        // Create the object we want to bind to the repeater
        ObjectToBind objectToBind = new ObjectToBind();

        // Here is what causes data loss
        ((IList<ObjectToBind>)repeater.DataSource).Add(objectToBind);
        repeater.DataBind();
    };
}

protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

**CustomControlWithDropDownLists.ascx:**

```xml
<%-- Some dropdown lists --%>
<asp:Button ID="deleteControl" runat="server" Text="Delete control" />
```

**CustomControlWithDropDownLists.ascx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    deleteControl.Click += (sndr, args) =>
    {
        // ... Delete the control ...

        ((Button)sndr).NamingContainer.Visible = false;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had done something similar in the past and found this link from c-sharp corner helpful. 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/10913/add-dynamic-row-using-repeater.aspx

The key element for me if memory servers is using the ViewState object and binding accordingly.

myObject = ViewState["MyData"]; etc.

( I am sorry I don't have access to my code at the moment )

Answer (score 0):

You are loosing the data because of View state.
View State losses the data when we are redirecting to the another page.
View state only store the data for the specific page.
The moment you go to another page data is lost by view state.
& there are many chances of losing the data on the same page because of many reasons.
So, the best way to store the data is to use session variable.
Session stores the data even when you are redirecting to the another page.
It is the best way to store the data.

By default it stores the data for 20 minutes.

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to store anything in SessionState. What I do it pull the values out of the repeater, bind the repeater, then reinsert the values. It can all be done in the same function, hence you aren't storing anything anyway. But its extra work.